# Where should ENV variables be defined when running app in a swarm mode?

Tags: docker, devops, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

There's an environment variable defined in frontend's `Dockerfile`:

```
ENV APP_BACKEND_URL=http://localhost/
```

and gets read when Docker builds a frontend image, and the same variable is defined in `app.yml`:

```yaml
services:
  backend:
    [...]

  frontend:
    [...]
    environment:
      APP_BACKEND_URL: 'backend'
```

The config file above gets given as an argument to `docker stack deploy -c app.yml appli`.

I wonder which value gets eventually set up as the final one: the one from `Dockerfile` (built into the image), or the other one, from the `app.yml` file, that gets read last. In case of operating with Docker Compose, all variables present both in `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` were given values from `Dockerfile`; `docker-compose.yml` values were ignored. Does it work the same in case of Docker Swarm?

I ask the question because in the end my frontend doesn't read any value of the variable (console logs say about `undefined` value) and I'd like to know how to supply the value to be accessible/readable by the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variable is used in the Dockerfile, only the Dockerfile definition has any effect.

```sh
FROM busybox
ENV FOO=bar
RUN echo "$FOO" > /a-file.txt
CMD cat /a-file.txt
```

```sh
docker build -t an-image .
docker run -e FOO=quux --rm an-image
# prints "bar" from the Dockerfile definition
```

When the application runs, though, the Compose definition will take precedence.

```sh
FROM busybox
ENV FOO=bar
CMD echo FOO is "$FOO"
```

```sh
docker build -t another-image .
docker run --rm -e FOO=quux another-image
# prints "FOO is quux" from the runtime definition
```

I would not expect this to work differently in Swarm.

> my frontend doesn't read any value of the variable (console logs say about `undefined` value)

For many front-end applications, you can run a Node server in a container, but that actually serves up Javascript code to a browser to run, and the application actually runs in the browser.  The browser isn't in Docker (and even isn't necessarily on the same host) and so it can't use Docker networking, environment variables defined only on the server, and so on.

If you're building your application using webpack, its [EnvironmentPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/) can cause `process.env` variables to be defined, but this is generally run when you're building the application's image and not when you're serving it.